# Facebook inline music player

Tags: facebook, api, streaming

I have created an application that allow users to share a preview of a song with their status and post to their wall. Just yesterday, the post will have an inline flash player allowing others to play it. But when I'm checking today, the inline player is removed and the song file  become a link for other to download.

Has facebook remove the inline player?? Or they have change their API for music streaming??

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Probably FB has removed an embedded audio player. See this bug.
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/267716143318745